# Solr : Make XML as response in Solr 4.8.1

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am using solr 4.8.1. 
When I execute any query for testing purpose from Dashboard I get response in JSON(BY DEFAULT)
Can I change it and make XML as default.
Plz refer below screen.
I am taking about dashboard only.
[image]

Thanks for looking here.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default values for your requestHandlers (which is what responds when a query is sent to /query or /select etc.), is set in solrconfig.xml. Here's the example from example/solr in the distribution:

```
<!-- A request handler that returns indented JSON by default -->
<requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="wt">json</str>
        <str name="indent">true</str>
        <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Changing `wt` to `xml` will give you a requestHandler that returns it response as XML by default, unless overridden at query time with the `wt` parameter. There might be parts of the web interface that assumes the response will be json, but I'm pretty sure those supply a value for `wt` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there is administration for web UI defaults, but you can change html easily:

in

> solr-4.8.1\example\solr-webapp\webapp\tpl\query.html

change order of options

```
<select name="wt" id="wt" title="The writer type (response format).">
      <option>xml</option>
      <option>json</option>
      <option>python</option>
      <option>ruby</option>
      <option>php</option>
      <option>csv</option>
</select>
```

Whatever option you put on first will be default, or set it selected:

`<option selected="selected">`

You may also change this html  in war file in solr-4.8.1\example\webapps.

Note that path is relative to example from 4.8.1 release